# Android: How to call call ndk function from AsyncTask?

Tags: android-ndk, android-asynctask

I have a lot of jni calls in my Android projects which work like a charm but this one I just can't get right: When trying to call a jni function from an AsyncTask in Android I get this error message:

```
11-30 10:07:20.130: W/dalvikvm(16555): No implementation found for native Lcom/company/MainView$MyAsyncTask;.MyFunction (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

When usually the jni function declaration works like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_company_MainView_myFunction()...
```

how would i declare it when calling from an AscnyTask?
I didn't find the answer on Google and I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_company_MainView$MyAsyncTask_myFunction()
```

and

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_company_MainView_MyAsyncTask_myFunction()
```

Or is this not possible at all?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is how do  you define a JNI function from within an inner class, and setup the appropriate declaration in your C/C++ code. I have no idea how to do that and was unable to find anything on the net about this. I would instead move the functionality into another class (which is not an inner class), and then call that function from your AsyncTask. Technically you should be able to do this if your AsyncTask was not an inner class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried that and it works, except that it comes from a different thread ID now and crashes then :)

Comment: 11-30 11:46:31.985: W/dalvikvm(20386): JNI WARNING: threadid=13 using env from threadid=1

Comment: even though I am not using _env_ as such.

Comment: I have now set the JVM in my first JNI  call with: `env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);` and then get it again with `jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0);` but that doesnt seem to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can run `javah` tool to generate C/C++ declarations for the native methods you declare in your Java code. In your specific case,

```
javah -classpath bin/classes com/company/MainView$MyAsyncTask
```

will produce the following header:

```
JNIEXPPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_company_MainView_00024MyAsyncTask_MyFunction(JNIRnv *, jobject, jstring);
```

Regarding the threading problem, AsyncTask may call your function each time from a different thread, but each time the call will provide the correct `env` as the first parameter, and you don't need `AttachCurrentThread()` because you do not create this thread in your native code.